# How do you call a function in a struct in the init function?

Tags: swift

I am looking to have a re-useable function in a struct that I can call in my init method. However, when I do this I get the following error.

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

How can I use `calculateValue` in my `init` method without raising this error? I will be using the `calculateValue` function in other parts of my struct so I don't want it to live in my `init` function.

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Int

    init(face: Face, suit: Suit) {
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = self.calculateValue(face: face)
    }

    private func calculateValue(face: Face) -> Int {
        if face == Face.two { return 2 }
        if face == Face.three { return 3 }
        if face == Face.four { return 4 }
        if face == Face.five { return 5 }
        if face == Face.six { return 6 }
        if face == Face.seven { return 7 }
        if face == Face.eight { return 8 }
        if face == Face.nine { return 9 }
        return 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions.

1. Make `calculateValue` a static function. This works since it doesn't depend on any state.

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Int

    init(face: Face, suit: Suit) {
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = Card.calculateValue(face: face)
    }

    private static func calculateValue(face: Face) -> Int {
        if face == Face.two { return 2 }
        if face == Face.three { return 3 }
        if face == Face.four { return 4 }
        if face == Face.five { return 5 }
        if face == Face.six { return 6 }
        if face == Face.seven { return 7 }
        if face == Face.eight { return 8 }
        if face == Face.nine { return 9 }
        return 10
    }
}
```

2. Move the functionality to return a value to the `Face` enum. Here's a partial guess at your `Face` enum with a computed `value` property:

```
enum Face {
    case two
    case three
    case jack

    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .two:
            return 2
        case .three:
            return 3
        default:
            return 10
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `Card` becomes:

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Int

    init(face: Face, suit: Suit) {
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = face.value
    }
}
```

Though now you don't even need the `value` property or you can make it a computed property.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to declare the enum with `Int` raw value. Assigning the initial raw value is sufficient, the compiler infers the sequence

```
enum Face : Int {
    case two = 2, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king, ace
}
```

and in `Card` get the value with a computed property which returns the raw value of `face` if it's less than 10 otherwise 10.

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    
    var value: Int { 
       return face.rawValue < 10 ? face.rawValue : 10
    }
}
```

The init method is for free.

Answer (score 0):

How about moving this into `Face` itself, e.g…

```
enum Face {
    case two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, jack, queen, king

    var value: Int {
        switch self {
        case .two: return 2
        case .three: return 3
        case .four: return 4
        case .five: return 5
        case .six: return 6
        case .seven: return 7
        case .eight: return 8
        case .nine: return 9
        default: return 10
        }
    }
}
```

then your init can be…

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Int
    
    init(face: Face, suit: Suit) {
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = face.value
    }    
}
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that! That would solve this problem. In saying that, is it possible to use `self` functions in the `init` function?

Comment: @Charklewis Can you clarify what you mean by "`self` functions"?

Comment: @Charklewis Yes, you can use instance methods in the `init` method but only after all uninitialized properties have been initialized. Your issue is trying to call an instance method before `value` has been set. It doesn't matter that you are calling the method to set `value`.

Answer (score -1):

Let me make another suggestion: Just make your `Face` value have an `Int` raw value:

```
enum Face: Int {
    case ace   = 1
    case two   = 2
    case three = 3
    case four  = 4
    case five  = 5
    case six   = 6
    case seven = 7
    case eight = 8
    case nine  = 9
    case ten   = 10
    case jack  = 11
    case queen = 12
    case king  = 13
}
```

At that point, you can just set `self.value = face.rawValue`. However, you shouldn't do that, because you'd have a split source of truth. The `Card` structs don't need a copy of the value. They can just access the value of the face, which they already contain:

```
struct Card {
    let face: Face
    let suit: Suit
    
    init(face: Face, suit: Suit) {
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
    }
    
    var value: Int { self.face.rawValue }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in this case (no pun intended) because `ten`, `jack`, `queen`, and `king` all need a value of 10.

Comment: @HangarRash Ah good catch, I didn't notice that. That sounds specific to some particular card game, not cards themselves. Assuming the game is called abc, It might make sense to have something like `var abcValue: Int { min(rawValue, 10) }`.